# Adding/Inserting text box for multiple cells simultaneously in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel

How to add or insert text box for multiple cells simultaneously in Microsoft excel? I am able to add individually for each cell, also it stays with the cell when respective row size change, trying to find a quick way to add for multiple cells. I tried selecting multiple cells and Insert > Text Box. It did not work.

Comment: Needs VBA probably as mentioned in a comment to your previous question.

Comment: Does copying cells (with inserted text box) work?